# Split the rows and organize as multi columed row using Google Sheets formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a table with n rows with data, the rows are required to be placed to the right.
Which is the chunk size, as shown

Make a copy of sheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aitrEnBpL7VV_qiylF4d00tLcKq9efU99hdO-5fa1RM/copy

[image]

The chink size is a variable and when chunk is changed the formula needs to auto adjust the result.

I have tried with

```
=transpose(flatten(query(ARRAYFORMULA(A2:F8),"select * limit 4 offset 0")))
```

but my formula needs manual reasoning and update of the formula when the table changes which is not feasible. A single formula that does the job accepting chunk size is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
=let(a,B11*columns(A$2:F$8),b,roundup((rows(A2:F8)*columns(A2:F8))/a),makearray(b,a,lambda(r,c,iferror(index(flatten(A$2:F$8),(r-1)*a+c)))))
```

- for the reference I had the `chunk number` entered in the cells `B11` and `B17`

[image]

---

If and when the [new functions](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/200022527?hl=en) are active & operational fo ya; you can also use this simple one:

```
=wraprows(tocol(A2:F8),B11*columns(A2:F8),)
```

[image]

Comment: You are really a rocking man. Thank you very much

Comment: when the new functions [resume back](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/200022527?hl=en&msgid=202965915) around this 27th, you can also try the alternative simpler formula I added to the answer.